# CDF of Uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

The problem is:
$Y \sim Unif[0,\theta]$ and we define $X = -Y$.

We want to find $ f_X(x)$ and $F_X(x).$

My solution:
$$F_X(x) = P(X<x)=P(Y>-x)=\int_{-x}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta} d\theta}$$

But from here I am unsure.I start the problem in this way because if I find the **cumulative distribution function**, i can derive it to find the **Probability Density Function**.

Comment: Make sure that what you’ve done so far is correct. Then after that why don’t you calculate the integral? This gives you the CDF of X. Then after that you differentiate to find the PDF of X. After that you are done.

Comment: I would have thought you wanted to integrate over $y$ rather than $\theta$, and the density is only positive for some $y$, so $\int\limits_{-x}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta} } \mathbf I_{0\le y\le \theta} \,dy$

Comment: $Y$ takes values in $[-\theta,0]$ So the integral goes only up to $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I would have thought $Y$ only takes values in $[0,\theta]$

Comment: @Henry if i solve the integral i have :$$\left [ \frac{y}{\theta}I_{[0,\theta]} \right ]_{-x}^{+\infty} = +\infty-\frac{x}{\theta}I_{[0,\theta]} = +\infty$$ what's i am doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac{y}{\theta}I_{[0,\theta]} =0$ when $y>\theta$ or $y <0$

Comment: @Henry I finally understood thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF of the continuous uniform random variable Y on the interval $[0,\theta]$ is $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ for values of $y$ in the given interval.

Therefore, we note that to find the PDF of X, we can do the following:

$F_X(x) = P(X<x)=P(Y>-x)=\int_{-x}^{\theta}{\frac{1}{\theta} dy}$

*Note: the reason tht we go up to $\theta$ is that the PDF is $0$ for any value of x outside of the interval $[0,\theta]$*

This evaluates to $F_X(x)=1+\frac{x}{\theta}=\frac{x+\theta}{\theta}$ by solving the integral. By differentiating we can find $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$ and so we are done as we have found both the PDF and CDF of $X$.

Therefore, $X$~$Uniform[-\theta,0]$ which should be expected if we refer back to the definition of $X$ as being equal to $-Y$.

Comment: Why is the integral up to $0$ rather than up to $\theta$?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer. Thanks for the correction; slightly misread the question at first @Henry

Comment: Thanks for the help i finally understood!